# Generic func transfer from view controller to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

How can I make input data in **func** `as? ViewController`?

```
private func toVC<T>(_ id: String, vc: T.Type) {
    if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as? T {
        if let window = self.window, let rootVC = window.rootViewController {
            var currVC = rootVC
            let navVC = UINavigationController()
            while let presentVC = currVC.presentedViewController {
                currVC = presentVC
            }
            navVC.viewControllers = [vc]
            currVC.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I get error `Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected element type 'UIViewController'` in `navVC.viewControllers = [vc]`.

How to right create func?

**UPD**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change method signature as below specifying `T` of type `UIViewController`,

```
private func toVC<T: UIViewController>(_ id: String, vc: T.Type) {
```

---

To pass `data` for specific controller,

```
private func toVC<T>(_ id: String, vc: T.Type, data: Any) {
    if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as? T {
        if let window = self.window, let rootVC = window.rootViewController {
            var currVC = rootVC
            let navVC = UINavigationController()
            while let presentVC = currVC.presentedViewController {
                currVC = presentVC
            }
            (vc as? MyViewController1)?.data = data
            (vc as? MyViewController2)?.data = data
            navVC.viewControllers = [vc]
            currVC.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use `generic` data for transfer from VC to VC in your func? I means this
`vc.id = id (String type)`
`vc.data = data ([String: Any] type)`

Comment: so I can't address to any controller? do I necessarily have to access the right controllers to pass the correct data?

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев `UIViewController` or `UINavigationController` itself doesn't hold any property where you can pass any `data`. You can create your own `BaseViewController` that has the `data` property and make all your `viewController`'s child of that. Or extend `UIViewController` to have a `data` property([one of many ways](https://medium.com/@valv0/computed-properties-and-extensions-a-pure-swift-approach-64733768112c)).

Comment: nice solution, I'll try